# How to create a discrete grid representation of a continuous polygon?

Tags: algorithm, discrete-mathematics

I have a number of continuous 2D shapes that I would like to map onto a discrete NxM grid at some resolution to then run a path planning algorithm in the discrete space. What are some methods or algorithms to do this?

Comment: The title corresponds to problem of **polygon rasterization**

Comment: What have you tried / researched so far? Share **YOUR** findings.

Comment: @MBo Thank you that is exactly what I needed. I just wasn't sure what this problem was called.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It basically depends on implementation details and main scenarios.

1. In case the map is changing not very often and you would like to use it many times it would make sense to preprocess the map to fill obstacles on the grid to make the check of we could go through the cell a fast and easy task.
2. The counter approach is to keep obstacles separately. Here you win in preprocessing time but the check for obstacles is calculation consuming (you need to check all 2D shapes to understand if you are crossing the line) and your main goal is to optimize it. One of the obvious optimizations are bounding boxes (see Axis-aligned minimum bounding box https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Minimum_bounding_box) or bounding circles (see Bounding sphere https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bounding_sphere). The idea is to check the 2DShape if only you are nearby and check easily if you are far from the obstacle. In Axis-aligned bounding box you need to check both **x_min <= x <= x_max** and **y_min <= y <= y_max** in case of circles you need to check one **(x-x0)^2+(y-y0)^2<=r^2** which is better.

You could try to combine both approaches by using the cache in the following way:

1. In case you never checked the cell if it's an obstacle or not use
   the 2nd approach with its own optimizations. Save the result in the cell cache.
2. In case you already checked the cell use cache value
3. In case there is a new obstacle on the map, invalidate cached values of all cells in the new 2Dshare bounding box/circle.

You also need to implement pathfinding algorithm using **A*** for example if it's part of the question (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/A*_search_algorithm) and method to check if the point is inside the 2D Share (one of the options is http://alienryderflex.com/polygon/)